# Numpy Array with Multiple dtypes not formatting correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Maybe this is a stupid question but I've never seen this behavior before and I'm not sure the correct term to google!

If I load my array this way:

```
A= np.loadtxt(csv,dtype='a100')
```

I get something in this format (it's a 2D array). I'm used to this format because I know it's fast, and I know how to find the index of an element easily with rows and columns.

```
[[a,1],[b,2]]
```

However, because my array has both strings and floats, when I load my array in I get a different result.

```
A= np.loadtxt(csv,dtype='a100,float')
```

Result:`[(a,1),(b,2)]`

My goal here is to be able to quickly search the array based upon the string in the first column, and then perform a numerical operation on the second column.

Is it better to keep it in a single dtype which gives me indexing [[]], and then somehow convert that string to a float to do the numerical operation and then write it back?

Can I still perform all of my same searching and indexing using a combined dtype, while still maintaining the speed of numpy?

Am I completely off in the weeds here?

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` darrays have to be homogeneous (that is, all elements have to have the same data type). Since `np,loadtxt()` finds different value types it assumes that you want a vector of a complex dtype rather than a 2-D array.

Comment: I see, so can I convert something I find in a homogenous array into a number, perform the operation and then write it back as a string? Do you know what I could Google for more information?

Comment: You may need to think more carefully about your requirements. Take a look at [this page from the numpy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) to learn more about field access. I wouldn't consider storing numbers as strings and converting them. It would be horribly inefficient.

Comment: What would you recommend then? Two different arrays with two different data types? I need a fast way to search and index decently large arrays.

Comment: [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) can cope with columns of different data types, so you might consider that if Oliver W's suggestions won't fill your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could continue with the structured dtype that you have generated. For example:

```
$ cat data.csv
a 1
b 3 
c 4
d 5
e 0
f 8
```

You can perform an operation on the 2nd column based on values in the first column:

```
>>> data = np.loadtxt('data.csv', dtype='a100,int')
>>> data.dtype
dtype([('f0', 'S100'), ('f1', '<i8')])
>>> data.dtype.names
('f0', 'f1')
```

Because I didn't specify any particular names for the columns in the `dtype` parameter to `np.loadtxt`, numpy automatically assigns `f0` and `f1` for the columns (from "field0" and "field1").

You can now use the indexing based on those field names:

```
>>> def some_processing(arr):  # example function to simulate some processing
...     return (arr < 'e') & (arr > 'b')
...
>>> data['f1'][some_processing(data['f0'])]
array([4, 5])
```

These structured arrays work similar to the typical n-dimensional arrays that you're used to but that are homogeneous (i.e. all elements are of the same type), but you can't group numerical indices within the same set of square brackets (so no `data[:3,'f1']`, but `data[:3]['f1']` or `data['f1'][:3]` are fine).